# How I can maintain an active session in Magento?

Tags: session

Anyone know how I can keep a user session within Magento , I wish that even if the user closes the browser or turn off the computer to access my website your account or session is still open , as I can do it active ? so far I have only lengthened the time Cookie, someone will know a method that can be applied or how this is done ?